# Package fracdiff of R fails to install in Linux Mint

Tags: r, linux, installation, forecast

I am installing the package `forecast`. However, I get a persistent error because the package `fracdiff` fails with this error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lblas
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
/usr/share/R/share/make/shlib.mk:6: recipe for target 'fracdiff.so' failed
make: *** [fracdiff.so] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘fracdiff’
* removing ‘/home/mario/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/fracdiff’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘fracdiff’ had non-zero exit status
```

Normally, when I see `had non-zero exit status`, it is for me a clue telling me that I should go to Synaptic and search for the library `r-cran-fracdiff`. However, this library is not present in my repositories, and don't really know how to solve this issue.

Any idea?

Comment: [How to make sure the numpy BLAS libraries are available as dynamically-loadable libraries?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6789368/608639)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lXXX" tells you that you should be looking for a library named something like "libXXX-dev".

In this case I would install `libblas-dev` and perhaps also `liblapack-dev`, [as explained here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/623578/installing-blas-and-lapack-packages).